# No puedo imprimir el resultado en consola

Tags: java

Alquiler de Películas → Debe contener el método MAIN, en dicha clase se deben de crear un objeto CLIENTE y otro de Película Infantil. Y finalmente se debe de imprimir en consola un reporte, el cual muestre la información del alquiler, tal y como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema a la hora de imprimir la información de la película

```
Cliente Cliente1 = new Cliente("1\n", "Hersann\n", "Heredia\n" ,"hfonseca_07@\n", "123456\n", "M\n");
Pelicula Pelicula_infantil = new Infantiles("ABC001", "Rapidos y Furiosos", "2018", "www.mega.com", Boolean.TRUE, "Disney\n");
Pelicula_Alquilada alquiler_cliente1 = new Pelicula_Alquilada("01/02/2020\n", 5);

public class Infantiles extends Pelicula{

    private String productora;    

    public Infantiles(String codigo, String titulo, String año_publicacion,
            String descarga, Boolean trailer, String productora) {
        super(codigo, titulo, año_publicacion, descarga, trailer);
        this.productora = productora;
    }

    public String getproductora() {
        return productora;
    }
    
    public void setProductora(String productora) {
        this.productora = productora;
    }
   
    public String toString() {
        return  "Nombrede la productora: " + productora;
                /*+"Codigo: "+ codigo 
                +"Titulo: "+ titulo 
                +"Año de publicacion: "+ año_publicacion
                +"URL de descarga: "+descarga 
                + "Trailer: "+ trailer ;*/
    }
}
```

por algun motivo cuando imprimo la informacion que se me pude en el cuadro blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor pulsa en [edit] y redacta mejor la pregunta, poniendo el código adecuadamente.

Comment: tienes código comentado, esa podría ser la razón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razòn es simplemente que tu mètodo `toString()` de la clase `Infantiles`
tiene comentada informaciòn, ademàs debes hacer uso del `\n` para que imprima en cada linea la informaciòn.

```
   public String toString() {
        return  "Nombre de la productora: " + productora 
                +"\nCodigo: "+ codigo 
                +"\nTitulo: "+ titulo 
                +"\nAño de publicacion: "+ año_publicacion
                +"\nURL de descarga: "+descarga 
                + "\nTrailer: "+ trailer ;
    }
```